# Running web.run_app() along with another async program : Python

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, event-loop, python-socketio

Currently I am working on a project which involves usage of Asynchronous functions, due to the usage of certain set of libraries. My code runs fine as long as I don't integrate a web-socket server implementing functionality in my code.
But, I wish to stream the output 'Result' continuously in a websocket stream. So, I tried integrating websocket from socketio library as an AsyncServer.
Firstly, in my code, I want to gather all my inputs, and keep displaying the possible Result in a terminal. Once my inputs are finalized, I wish my result to be streamed over Websocket.

Initially, I just tried using web.run_app() in an asynchronous task in the main thread. Refer code below with #Type-1 comments. (Make sure that the lines with comment #Type-2 should be commented out). But I get the following exception "This event loop is already running".

I thought maybe if I run web.run_app() in a separate thread, then this issue might not come up. So, I changed my implementation slightly.  Refer code below with #Type-2 comments. (Make sure that the lines with comment #Type-1 should be commented out). Now, I get another issue "set_wakeup_fd only works in main thread of the main interpreter".

Can someone please help me solve this issue, and let me know how must I use web.run_app()?

Here is the code:

```
import os, sys
import asyncio
import platform
import threading
import socketio
import json

from aioconsole import ainput
from aiohttp import web
from array import *

Result = -1 
Inputs_Required = True 
Input_arr = array('i')

sio = socketio.AsyncServer() 
app = web.Application() 
sio.attach(app)
Host = "192.168.0.7" 
Port = 8050        

async def IOBlock():
    global Input_arr
    global Inputs_Required
    
    while(True):
        response = input("Enter new input? (y/n): ")
        if('y' == response or 'Y' == response):
            Input = input("Enter number to be computed: ")
            Input_arr.append(int(Input))
            break
        elif('n' == response or 'N' == response):
            Inputs_Required = False
            break
        else:
            print("Invalid response.")

async def main():
    global Results
    global Inputs_Required
    global Input_arr
    
    WebSocketStarted = False
    #WebSocketThread = threading.Thread(target = WebStreaming, daemon = True) #Type-2
            
    try:
        while True: 
            if(Inputs_Required == True):
                Task_AddInput = asyncio.create_task(IOBlock())
                await Task_AddInput
            elif (WebSocketStarted == False):
                WebSocketStarted = True
                #WebSocketThread.start() #Type-2
                WebTask = asyncio.create_task(WebStreaming()) #Type-1
                await WebTask #Type-1
            
            if(len(Input_arr) > 0):
                Task_PrintResult = asyncio.create_task(EvaluateResult()) 
                await Task_PrintResult
                
    except Exception as x:
        print(x)
    finally: 
        await Cleanup()

async def WebStreaming(): #Type-1
#def WebStreaming(): #Type-2
    print("Starting web-socket streaming of sensor data..")
    Web_loop = asyncio.new_event_loop #Type-1 or 2
    asyncio.set_event_loop(Web_loop) #Type-1 or 2
    web.run_app(app, host=Host, port=Port)
    
async def EvaluateResult():
    global Input_arr
    global Result
    
    Result = 0
    for i in range (0, len(Input_arr)):
        Result += Input_arr[i]
    print(f"The sum of inputs fed so far = {Result}.")
    await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def Cleanup():
    global Input_arr
    global Inputs_Required
    global Result
    
    print("Terminating program....")
    Result = -1
    Inputs_Required = True
    for i in reversed(range(len(Input_arr))):
        del Input_arr[i]

@sio.event
async def connect(sid, environ):
    print("connect ", sid) 
    
@sio.event
async def OnClientMessageReceive(sid, data):
    global Result
    
    print("Client_message : ", data)
    while True: 
        msg = json.dumps(Result)
        print(msg)
        await sio.send('OnServerMessageReceive', msg)

@sio.event
def disconnect(sid):
    print('disconnect ', sid)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```